# Open popup on notification click

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible from within the context of a [desktop notification](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) to open a extension popup on click? See example code below:

```
var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification();

notification.addEventListener('click', function() {
    notification.cancel();
    // TODO: trigger extension popup open here.
});
notification.show();
```

Worth mentioning: the actual notification is created by the extension event page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a way to open the popup programmatically isn't available yet.

You *can* open a new tab with the same page, though.